# Is it possible to restrict the permissions to only allow REST API calls in Bitbucket Server?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-server

I was wondering if it is possible to restrict the credentials of a user to only allow to perform REST API calls (ideally selected ones).

I would like to restrict the user created for Jenkins purposes on to be able to:

1. trigger the build (using POST commit hook),
2. update the build status (using [Build Status API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/server/docs/latest/how-tos/updating-build-status-for-commits.html))

Thanks.

Comment: it's not clear enough what do you want. To clone via REST? You can't, REST is only for server-side actions. You want to trigger a build? Bitbucket Server(not a cloud) doesn't know to build anything.

Comment: You are right, reworded the question.

Comment: the first bullet still isn't clear enough. post commit hook is a client side hook. did you mean post recieve hook? anyway, server side hooks are triggered after/before git push and not through  REST

Comment: 1. other system will trigger the build using post receive hook by calling Jenkins HTTP request to start the build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is - no. There are no specific permission for the REST api.

In details:

1. A post received hook runs after a push operation. In case of Bitbucket Server it runs also after a merge of a pull request. The [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/5.1.3/bitbucket-rest.html#idm45319071824928) says:

   > The authenticated user must have REPO_WRITE permission for the
   >   repository that this pull request targets to call this resource.

So, you must give a write access to the user in order to trigger a post-receive hook

2. According to the [documentation](https://legacy-developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/5.1.3/bitbucket-build-rest.html#idm45610062134432):

> The authenticated user must have LICENSED permission or higher to call
>   this resource.

So you can use a user with minimal permissions